# django delete object with html button

Tags: python, django

I have a simple site project in Django and I have movies lists in man page and movies details in the second page.

I want to add a delete button on movies details tab where user can delete the movies object.

**views.py**

```
def movies_list(request):
    return render(request, 'movies.html',{'movies':movies.objects.all()})


def movies_details(request,slug):
    movies_details=MyModel.objects.all()
    det=get_object_or_404(movies_details, slug_name=slug)
    return render(request, 'movies_details.html',{'movies_details':movies_details,'det':det})
```

what is the better method to do that ?

something like this using new view :

```
def delete(request, id):
    note = get_object_or_404(Note, pk=id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('movies_details.views.movies_details'))
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$','project.app.views.delete'),
```

or some like this ?

```
if request.POST.get('delete'):
    obj.delete()
```

or use some Django form ?

Comment: "What is best" is off-topic in this Q&A website because it generates opinion-based answers and flame-wars. Unless you are having trouble just pick the one you like more. That said, you can also use the DELETE HTTP method instead of GET or POST.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DeleteView` functionality of django. I think that will be the better one.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class DeleteTaskView(DeleteView):
     template_name = 'template/delete.html'
     model = Task
     pk_url_kwarg = 'id'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('movies_details.views.movies_details')
```

Comment: what changes I need to work with your code in my project for this ? on the `Task` only I use my model name ?and in the `template_name = 'template/delete.html'` can I use some template like `'movies_details.html'` ? and final what I need to write in my html template ?sorry but I am new thanx you

Comment: don't work your code I take syntax error at this line `pk_url_kwarg = 'id'`

Comment: @Mar, Sorry for late reply. You can use any name as of template and then in `pk_url_kwarg` instead of `id` use whatever you are passing in `url`.

Comment: `pk_url_kwarg` is for url ?and if that I want to delete is the image how to remove from server I mean the complete delete from media folder how to do this with your code ?